# Is there a way to extract all sentences containing a particular word?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I’d like to extract all sentences containing the word ‘apple’, including lower and upper case. The results can be displayed together in cell B1 or separated into other cells.

Sample Text in cell A1: 
An apple a day keeps the doctor away. But I don’t think they are yummy. I have never liked them. Apples aren’t my favourite, pears are.

Is there an Excel formula for this? Thank you.

Comment: Try using the find() function or substitute()

Comment: Is each sentence in its **own cell**, or are there several sentences within a **single** cell ??

Answer (score 1):

This works in Open Office, Google Docs, Excel, etc:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("apple",A22)),A22,"")
```

It gives this output:

[image: Example of function use in spreadsheet]

Comment: Instead of FIND, you would be better off with **SEARCH** , which is case-**in**sensitive. Then you could lose the **LOWER**.

Comment: Thanks, that is cleaner. I changed the answer to use SEARCH as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

## Sentence String Search

You might get away with a long formula for a few sentences, but I don't think that it would solve your task. So I've developed a User-defined function (UDF). Copy the code into a standard module.

```
Function SSS(ByVal SearchString As String, ByVal SearchText As String, _
        Optional ByVal SplitString As String = ".", _
        Optional ByVal JoinString As String = " ") As String

    Dim vnt As Variant  ' String Array
    Dim i As Long       ' String Array Element Counter
    Dim strB As String  ' String Builder

    vnt = Split(SearchText, SplitString)
    ' Loop through elements of String Array.
    For i = 0 To UBound(vnt) - 1 ' "-1" ie. Ignore text after last Split String.
        ' Check value of current element of String Array against SearchString.
        ' "vbTextCompare" determines case-INsensitivity (AA = aa = Aa = aA).
        If InStr(1, vnt(i), SearchString, vbTextCompare) Then
            ' Build the String
            If strB <> "" Then ' For all but the first found SearchString.
                strB = strB & JoinString & Trim(vnt(i)) & SplitString
              Else             ' Only for the first found SearchString.
                strB = Trim(vnt(i)) & SplitString
            End If
        End If
    Next

    SSS = strB

End Function
```

### Usage in Excel

`A1` contains `"apple"`
`A2` contains `"An apple a day keeps the doctor away. But I don’t think they are yummy. I have never liked them. Apples aren’t my favourite, pears are."`

In any other cell write the following formula:

```
=SSS(A1, A2)
```

to get the following result:

```
An apple a day keeps the doctor away. Apples aren’t my favourite, pears are.
```

### Remarks

In your case you can omit the parameters of the 3rd and 4th arguments:

- The 3rd argument is `SplitString` and is by default a `DOT` "."
- The 4th argument is `JoinString` and is by default a `SPACE` " ".